# Even data sampling with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that returns all points between two timestamps. If I do a particularly large timeslice (say 1 year), I might get 10000 rows. I want to be able to ask for a resolution (say 1 day) and have them evenly spaced  by 1 day, and receive back ~ 365 rows. Here is my query as it stands now:

```
SELECT *
      FROM checkins
      WHERE serial=${serial} AND created_at BETWEEN ${startTimestamp} AND ${endTimestamp}
      ORDER BY created_at DESC
      LIMIT ${limit}
      OFFSET ${offset}
```

Any ideas on a good strategy using Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have **PG 9.4+** this should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM checkins
JOIN (
  -- The below returns 366 created_at values within the two time points, inclusive
  SELECT precentile_disc(fraction/365.) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY created_at) 
  FROM checkins, generate_series(0, 365) f(fraction)
  WHERE serial = ${serial} AND created_at BETWEEN ${startTimestamp} AND ${endTimestamp}
) USING (created_at)
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

The [`percentile_disc()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE) gives you a discrete value from a sorted group according to the fraction specified, with the value being closest to the supplied fraction. In combination with [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) you get a series of such values at fractions `[0., 0.004, 0.008, ..., 1.]`. Then you join those values (the `created_at` values, not the fractions) back to the `checkins` table for the final result.

For **older versions** of PG, you can do it "manually" like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, rank() OVER (ORDER BY created_at) AS rnk
  FROM checkins
  WHERE serial = ${serial} AND created_at BETWEEN ${startTimestamp} AND ${endTimestamp}
) sub
WHERE rnk % extract(day from ${endTimestamp} - ${startTimestamp}) = 1
ORDER BY created_at;
```

This gives you 1 row for each day between `startTimestamp` and `endTimestamp`, so if they are a year apart you get 365 rows.

Comment: I only have PG 9.3 :(

Comment: That 2nd query returns: 'window functions not allowed in where clause'

Comment: Wrapped in a sub-query now.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Spent 20m on it. Something about:

WHERE rnk % extract(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP '2016-03-28 22:29:32.371' - '2015-03-28 22:29:32.371') = 1 gives a "operator does not exist: bigint % double precision

Comment: Nvm, got it. Had to cast them to ints.

Comment: After many years I've found it very helpful, thanks! However, I had to edit it a little to execute properly with the latest PG 15.1 (updating the answer).